# Not able to install M2eclipse plugin in NEON Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I have installed Eclipse Neon Milestone 4, Java 8, and Apache Maven 3.3.3 on my windows system. I am trying to install plugin :: ***M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.2*** in eclipse. I am getting error -
Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
**"m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components)" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed.**

But When I look in "Installation detail" I can't see Maven plugin there. Also no Maven menu option is coming when I am right clicking the project.

Please help to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem too. I'm using the same version of Eclipse, etc. It turns out that the "fix" was kind of subtle. When you go an install new software under the help option using "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases", then you select the maven option. On the next screen they say here's what your downloading...

I had to **select the two items by highlighting them** then press next and agree to the licenses for m2eclipse to install correctly. The first time when it didn't work I thought, okay great that's what I need, and then nothing happened. Hopefully that helps, I realize you're getting this answer about 10 months after you asked for help.